# SSRS table hide and not export to csv

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2016

I am looking at hiding a table in the report and not show during export to CSV based on a parameter. If the parameter is true, it should hide it in the report and export to CSV.

When I hide the table only in the report it works.

```
=iif(Parameters!parameter.Value=parameter_to_hide,True,False)
```

If I add the option of hiding the table in the report and in export to CSV, it does not work.

```
=iif(Parameters!parameter.Value=parameter_to_hide,Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV",False) AND iif(Parameters!parameter.Value=parameter_to_hide,Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV",False)
```

I also tried with no luck

```
=iif(Parameters!parameter.Value=parameter_to_hide,IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV", True, False),False)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot hide a table in a CSV export.

> PDF, HTML, and Excel export leverage “layout renderers” – a generally
>   more expensive export process which attempts to mimic the “look” you
>   created in Report Designer. CSV and XML are “data renderers”, and only
>   care about data. The difference is reflected in what a layout renderer
>   typically exports (basically everything) and what data renderers save
>   (not necessarily all of your columns).

--[MSDN Blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bimusings/2007/02/07/reporting-services-why-arent-all-my-report-columns-exporting-to-csv-andor-xml/)

There is a **DataElementOutput** property but you cannot set it with an expression (thanks, MS), so you would need to manually set it.

The only way I can think of around this is to have an IIF in every cell and display a blank if it's a CSV.